# zxing-js/ngx-scanner error: GET http://localhost:4200/noposter 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, npm, angular16

How to resolve this error in ngx scanner latest version at now (v16.0.1).

[image]

I found what causing this error but have no idea about resolving it!
[image]

I'm using angular 16.
Here is the link to the library:
[ngx-scanner](https://github.com/zxing-js/ngx-scanner)

Answer (score 0):

I hope after [this pull request](https://github.com/zxing-js/ngx-scanner/pull/530) this issue will be solved. Because this allows library users to bind the poster attribute of the video tag dinamically.

[image]

[image]